# How to say "just a precision" properly in English?

Tags: phrase-request

How to say "just a precision" properly in English? By "just a precision", I mean: I said statement X, but I would like to add a statement Y which refines statement X (= make it more precise). Statement Y is typically done sometime after, e.g. statement X was made in one email and statement Y was expressed in a subsequent email.

When I search on Google for "just a precision", it seems I only find French speakers, e.g.:

- https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/57909058 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704055655/https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/57909058))
- https://medium.com/@theotyburn/just-a-precision-on-the-use-of-statistics-in-this-example-819459c8982a ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704055706/https://medium.com/@theotyburn/just-a-precision-on-the-use-of-statistics-in-this-example-819459c8982a))
- https://sourceforge.net/p/gramps/mailman/message/20168682/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704055711/https://sourceforge.net/p/gramps/mailman/message/20168682/))

so I'm inferring native English speakers don't use this expression.

I thought of the following replacements but they aren't fully matching the meaning of "just a precision":

- addendum/corrigendum/erratum: it doesn't necessarily introduce a more precise statement.

Comment: "To be more precise" I would advise against saying "Just a precision" since, on first reading your title, I thought you meant *only* precision as in the sentence: "He was marked ONLY on his precision".

Comment: To be clear: "just a precision" makes no sense in English (as I think you realise). Often the best translation is "just a clarification".

Comment: juste une précision is  French not English. We say: just a clarification.

Comment: @Lambie "juste une précision is French not English" yes this is why I posted this question. Thanks, you're welcome to convert your comment suggesting the use of "just a clarification" into an answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted to add clarity or precision to some information you had previously given in vague or outline form, you could write "to clarify", "to be precise", or "to be exact", etc. This might be because you now realise that the recipient's (or recipients') understanding is incomplete or incorrect.

> Email A: When travelling for work purposes, meal allowances may be
> claimed in certain circumstances.
>
> Email B: To clarify/be precise/be exact, a meal allowance may be
> claimed only when the journey made for work purposes exceeds four
> hours in duration, is limited to 15 euros, and receipts must be provided.

Comment: The noun form is: just a clarification aka just to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

A very similar phrase in English is **more precisely**

An example of its use can be seen [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precisely) under examples:

> The next observation concerns the faces of a 2 -connected plane graph; more precisely it states that every face is an induced cycle.

However, this is typically used when the "refining statement" is in the same body of text as the first statement. It also typically used when a speaker/writer is refining their own statements.  **To be more specific,** could be used in a similar manner at the start of sentences, too.

---

For the examples you gave, "more precisely" really fit. I am not sure if there is a set phrase that we use in English in all of these places.

Looking at the three examples you gave, you could use the format of **"Just a [...]"** and fill in the blank with the type of comment you make.

That type could be a:

> "comment" (relatively neutral observation)
>
> "note" (similar to comment, but often constructive criticism)
>
> "correction" (if the statement is correcting a previous false statement with the truth)
>
> "question" (self-explanatory)
>
> "clarification" (to present information more truthfully/specifically than before)

For the first example I would probably use "clarification" or "correction". For your second example I would probably use "note".  And for your third example "question" would obviously be appropriate.

---

This is by no means exhaustive, but I thought these two formats were pretty close to OP's original phrase.

Answer (score 1):

When French speakers say "Juste une précision", they mean: "Just a clarification".

I don't know what else to say about this. :)